# Can this SQL constraint be written more simply?

Tags: sql, constraints, h2

To clarify - there will be up to 4 distinct players in the table, referenced by their ids.  I want to enforce this, i.e. no two ids are the same.

Also, because it's up to 4 players, some may be null.  Is potentially having many nulls like this a bad idea?  I don't think it does, but just to be sure, does `null == null` return false?

```
...
CHECK (playerid1 <> playerid2)
  AND (playerid1 <> playerid3)
  AND (playerid1 <> playerid4)
  AND (playerid2 <> playerid3)
  AND (playerid2 <> playerid4)
  AND (playerid3 <> playerid4)
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a common column, like a game id or something? You can always use `player1 NOT IN (SELECT playerid FROM table WHERE gameid=thisgameid)` (or some facsimile)

Comment: You say 'up to 4 players in each table' but you want to force a check constraint? What happens when a playerid is null or 0?

Comment: @BradChristie, I'll try that out, presumably `CHECK player1 NOT IN..` would be valid syntax?
@dwerner, that's why I wanted to clarify about null==null returning false, in which case, there could be 2 players and 2 nulls and it would pass the check, if the 2 players are different.

Comment: @c24w: I was trying to get an idea of the schema, not actually setting rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd use a separate table for this:

```
 create table game_players (
      game_id number, player_id number, player_position number
    );
```

Then you can add

- a UNIQUE constraint for game_id+player id (to enforce a player doesn't occur more than once per game)
- a UNIQUE constraint for game_id+player_position (to ensure a position is occupied by at most one player)
- a CHECK constraint for player_position to enforce it only has the values 1, 2, 3 or 4

This should achieve what you want in a somewhat cleaner (IMHO) way.

Comment: +1. And the `player1, player2, player3, player4`-like view could be implemented in the form of, well, a [VIEW](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_view).

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me to look into composite UNIQUE constraints, or whatever you might call them.  Thanks!

Comment: @c24w: Not composite, this answer suggests an in-between many-to-many table.  The `game` table would only have one `player` field, not four.

Comment: @Andomar: I was referring to the UNIQUE(col1,col2,...) as a 'composite' UNIQUE constraint.  Still, you guys clearly know what you're on about!  I'm still experimenting with my tables.

Answer (score 1):

Of your seven expressions, you have repeats e.g. `(playerid1 <> playerid2)`. The definitive set is limited to six.

I would prefer to have six different constraints, each with a meaningful name, in order to give granular error messages to the user e.g.

```
CONSTRAINT playerid2__duplicates__playerid1 CHECK ( playerid1 <> playerid2 ),
CONSTRAINT playerid3__duplicates__playerid1 CHECK ( playerid1 <> playerid3 ),
CONSTRAINT playerid4__duplicates__playerid1 CHECK ( playerid1 <> playerid4 ),
CONSTRAINT playerid3__duplicates__playerid2 CHECK ( playerid2 <> playerid3 ),
CONSTRAINT playerid4__duplicates__playerid2 CHECK ( playerid2 <> playerid4 ),
CONSTRAINT playerid4__duplicates__playerid3 CHECK ( playerid3 <> playerid4 )
```

It may be of interest to reveal I wrote the above using SQL:

```
WITH T 
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('playerid1'), 
                     ('playerid2'), 
                     ('playerid3'),
                     ('playerid4')
             ) AS T (c)
     )
SELECT 'CONSTRAINT ' 
       + T2.c + '__duplicates__' + T1.c 
       + ' CHECK ( ' + T1.c + ' <> ' + T2.c + ' ),'
  FROM T AS T1, T AS T2
 WHERE T1.c < T2.c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The ellipses were merely to indicate that it was only a section of the entire SQL statement.  I just discovered I repeated `playerid2 <> playerid3` as well as `playerid1 <> playerid2` - thanks for pointing that one out.

Comment: @c24w Thanks, I should have paid closer attention :)